# Exlode in php for DataBase

Tags: php

I am passing the check box value in url `like selected.php?aa=2,3,` and i want get the 2 and 3 value from datebase when i explode its not working

```
$mainclass=$_GET['aa'];  
$classarray = list($class) = explode(",", $mainclass);  
$classa = implode(',', $classarray);  
$makefeed = mysql_query("SELECT dbid FROM studentnew WHERE dbid IN ('".$classa."')");  
while ($cc = mysql_fetch_array($makefeed))   {  
  // code
  echo $cc['name'];
}
```

Comment: what is list($class) where does $class come from

Answer (score 0):

```
$mainclass  = $_GET['aa'];  
$classarray = explode(",", $mainclass);  
$classarray = array_walk($classarray, 'intval');
$classa     = implode(',', $classarray);

$makefeed = mysql_query("SELECT dbid FROM studentnew WHERE dbid IN (".$classa.")");
```